# A vector field satisfies both $\nabla\cdot v=0$ and $\Vert v \Vert = 1$

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis

It is trivial to satisfy just one of them. In 2D for example ($r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ below), $\nabla\cdot(x,-y) = 0$. However, $\Vert v \Vert = r$, so only the divergence condition is satisfied. On the other hand for $(x/r, y/r)$, we have $\Vert v \Vert = 1$ but $\nabla\cdot v=1/r$ instead of 0.

Note that the first one is a differential constraint, whereas the second one is only an algebraic constraint. Is there a standard name for this kind of problem that involves a mixture of both algebraic and differential operations?

**Edit**: A uniform unit vector field is excluded because it's trivial.

**Edit**: Solution in 2D

Thanks to the paper @LuisFerreira pointed to me, I can construct a 2D field that satisfies the requirement, except at some singular points. The proof in the paper is beyond me so unfortunately I can not explain why such singularity exists.

First: recognize that $v = \nabla^\perp \psi$, where $\psi$ is the stream function and the operation gives a 2D vector field $(\psi_y, -\psi_x)$. Then the divergence condition is satisfied automatically

Second: the norm constraint is $\Vert v \Vert = \Vert \nabla^\perp\psi \Vert = \Vert \nabla \psi \Vert = 1$. The 2nd equality is clear if you express them in components. $\Vert \nabla \psi \Vert = 1$ is the Eikonal equation, a classical solution of which is the distance field.

Example, the distance field to the origin is $\psi(x,y)=r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, so
$$
v = \nabla^\perp \psi = \left( \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, -\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \right)
$$

A plot

[image: example answer in 2d]

$v$ is divergence free and has unit length, but it's singular at the origin.

**Comment** In 3D we don't have *scalar* stream function so the problem can be quite different/difficult (we do have vector potential, which itself is a vector instead of scalar field, so I don't think it will help).

**Edit** Another 2D example based on the distance field of an ellipse. This one won't permit any analytical description.

[image: out of ellipse]

Comment: How does $\nabla\cdot(x,-y)=0$ satisfy $\nabla\cdot v=1$?

Comment: @TonyK I am very sorry. The title should say $\nabla\cdot v=0$ (i.e., $v$ is solenoidal), fixed.

Comment: I bet such a vector field cannot exist on a simply connected region of $\mathbb R^n$. Just an educated guess. If $v$ is defined on the whole of $\mathbb R^n$, this is motivated by the divergence theorem, which implies that $$\int_{\partial B} v\cdot n\, dS=0, $$ for all balls $B$ in $\mathbb R^n$ (here $\partial$ denotes the boundary). The fact that $\|v\|^2=1$ does not seem to be compatible with this, but this is just a feeling. (The simply connected case shouldn't be much different).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I have the same feeling, also just a feeling. But I can imagine a very noisy field where unit vectors point to different directions with equal probability. Then in an integral AND probabilistic sense, your surface integral is zero everywhere. Of course, this is a rather weak argument and only remotely answers the question.

Comment: @Taozi In a probabilistic sense, almost all vector fields are like that. Very irregular.

Comment: @Taozi: yes, but I feel that taking the limit of $$\frac{1}{\lvert \partial B\rvert}\int_{\partial B} v\cdot n\, dS=0$$ as the radius of $B$ tends to zero yields some interesting piece of information.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: This question is a dud. See my answer.

Comment: @TonyK: Well, I don't believe so, it is interesting. I still believe that the only solution that is defined on all of $\mathbb R^n$ is the uniform vector field, which is the one you gave. This is corroborated by the fact that the explicit example, given in the edit to this question, has a singularity at the origin. I haven't checked the reference given by Luis Ferreira, though.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thanks, I already learned something so I am glad I asked the question. When the domain is not simply connected, there are non-trivial solutions without singularity. In my example just remove a small circle bounding the origin. I believe there are also non-singular non-trivial solutions on a torus surface.

Answer (score 3):

Just take any unit vector $\mathbf{e}$, and set $v(x,y)=\mathbf{e}$ for all $x,y$.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified that beforehand, but I expect non-trivial solutions.

Comment: @Taozi: So why haven't you edited your question to reflect that?

Comment: It's fixed, didn't want to invalidate your answer due to my flawed description.

Comment: @Taozi: OK, that's a fair point. But I see you flagged it as an edit, so there's no harm done.

Answer (score 1):

These are usually called [Differential algebraic equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential-algebraic_system_of_equations), which involve a mixture of differential equations and algebraic constraints. Note that these are different from [algebraic differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_differential_equation), which are a whole other beast.

**EDIT:** It seems like you were also looking for an actual solution to this equation and I missed that, so I'll try to find some direction at least:
Since $\|v\|=1$, we can write $v(x,y)=(v_1(x,y),v_2(x,y))$ as $(cos(\theta(x,y)), sin(\theta(x,y)))$. Applying divergence to this expression, we arrive at $cos(\theta)\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}-sin(\theta)\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}=0$, which isn't a very nice PDE to deal with.

**EDIT:** [This](https://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~rignat/JFA_divS1.pdf) paper appears to have some interesting results, but might be too technical for what you're looking for.

Comment: Interesting, looks like a rather mature field. This maybe a stupid question, but how hard is DAE? I mean, compared with "pure" DE, how much extra burden is added to the analytical/numerical effort by introducing the algebraic constraint?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. ;)

Comment: @Taozi Honestly, I'm not very much into it, but from what I can tell, it's pretty harder than usual DE's. However, the hardest part is actually converting the system of differential-algebraic equations to a system of "ODE's", especially if the equation can't be written as an ODE with constraints (as, numerically, solving ODEs is pretty much solving iterated systems of algebraic equations). So, more optimization techniques should be used, I think.

I can't tell much about the analytical part yet, though.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry, I'm new here so I might miss some stuff... but the question felt like it was more about what this type of equations are, and not about getting a non trivial example for this particular one :P

Comment: @LuísFerreira Thanks to the paper your pointed out, some 2D solutions can be constructed (see my edit). However, they will contain singular points as pointed out by the paper.